# Geolocation and calculating distance

Tags: javascript, php, html, gps, geolocation

I have some project. I want to read current location of a mobile phone and calculate it's distance between some locations loaded from a database. Every part works perfectly apart but I can't make it cooperate. It seems that when I am calculating distance, location of the phone is not obtained yet (at least that what I think is the problem).

Please help me with finding solution! I would be very grateful.

TrackPosition.js:

```
var op, prev_lat, prev_long, info_string="", current_lat=0, current_long=0, wpid;


function format_time_component(time_component){
    op=document.getElementById("output");

    if(time_component<10)
        time_component="0"+time_component;
    else if(time_component.length<2)
        time_component=time_component+"0";

    return time_component;
}

function geo_success(position){ 
    info_string="";
    var d=new Date(); // Date object, used below for output messahe
    var h=d.getHours();
    var m=d.getMinutes();
    var s=d.getSeconds();

    var current_datetime=format_time_component(h)+":"+format_time_component(m)+":"+format_time_component(s);

    if(prev_lat!=position.coords.latitude || prev_long!=position.coords.longitude){
        prev_lat=position.coords.latitude;
        prev_long=position.coords.longitude;
        current_lat=position.coords.latitude;
        current_long=position.coords.longitude;

        info_string="Current positon: lat="+current_lat+", long="+current_long+
        " (accuracy "+Math.round(position.coords.accuracy, 1) +"m) " + current_datetime + "<br>";

    }


    if(info_string)
        op.innerHTML=info_string;
}


function geo_error(error) {
    switch(error.code)
    {
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            op.innerHTML="Timeout!";
        break;
    };
}

function posInit()
{
    if(!!navigator.geolocation){
        wpid=navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success, geo_error, {
                                                                            enableHighAccuracy:true, 
                                                                            maximumAge:30000, 
                                                                            timeout:27000});
    } else{
        op.innerHTML="ERROR: Your Browser doesnt support the Geo Location API";
    }
}

window.onload=posInit();
```

index.php:

```
<?php
class Package{
    public $id;
    public $names;
    public $surname;
    public $street;
    public $city;
    public $country;
    public $long;
    public $lat;

    public function __construct($id, $names, $surname, $street, $city, $country) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->names = $names;
        $this->surname = $surname;
        $this->street = str_replace(' ', '+', $street);
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->country = $country;
        $this->getPosition();   
    }

    public function getPosition(){
        $address = $this->street . "+" . $this->city . "+" .$this->country;

        $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $address . "&sensor=false&region=UK";
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        $this->lat = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $this->long = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    }

    public function toJSON(){
        $json = array(
            'id' => $this->id,
            'names' => $this->names,
            'surname' => $this->surname,
            'street' => $this->street,
            'city' => $this->city,
            'country' => $this->country,
            'lat' => $this->lat,
            'longs' => $this->long
        );
        return json_encode($json);
    }
}

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("COURIERKIT", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM packages");

$packages = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $packages[] = new Package($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5]);
}


mysql_free_result($result);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="TrackPosition.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Distance.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="output" id="output"></div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var s = <?php print $packages[0]->toJSON(); ?>; 

           document.write(distance(current_lat, current_long, s.lat, s.longs));

       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: think you need to calculate the distances within the geolocation callback function

Comment: But how can I get coordinates of some location from database inside the geolocation callback function?

Comment: The Geolocation function works fine. The PHP script I guess also works fine and you use that to populate a javascript variable 's' - The PHP script will always complete before the page renders so the javascript variable can be written out to the page (as you do above) before you include the other javascript files. The page then loads and the geolocation function goes off and does it's thing - and because you are declaring the variable 's' globally the callback function *should* have access to 's' - which means the callback function can pass the value of 's' to the distance calculating function

Comment: But it doesn't. Whenever I pass 's' to callback function it is seen as undefined. I tried couple of combinations to achieve this but without any success. This is very strange... I am loading TrackPosition.js after declaring 's'. I'm not getting any error about not declared variable but values are still not filled. :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/qs9eL/ ~ seems to work there but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I checked type of 's' in external js file and it shows: "number". I don't know what is going on! It's driving me crazy.

Comment: assign it as a different variable name - perhaps you have a conflict? When I tried using 's' like you did I too got a number - so i changed that to 'sdata' and all seemed ok. I see where it get's the number from now - within the geo_success function you assign 's' as seconds